# How to select any element from the web element with "display: none" attribute using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to select any element from the web element with `display: none` attribute that looks like this:

```
<div class="some_class">
  <select id="some_id" class="some_select_class" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1" data-isleaf="false" data-catid="3" data-special_message="" data-adtypeid="0">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-isleaf="true" data-catid="4" data-special_message="" data-adtypeid="1">2</option>    
  </select>
</div>
```

I can do it manually from a web browser, but I need to do it via Selenium in Python. Unfortunately, when I have the following code:

```
try:
  element = selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'some_id')))
  selenium.webdriver.support.ui.Select(element).select_by_value('1')
except Exception as ex:
  print(ex)
```

`WebDriverWait` throws an exception with the following info:

> Message: ''

The type of the exception is `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`

How can I achieve the interaction of this element? How can I select any element in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Selenium does not interact with elements that have `display: none` set.  It only interacts with visible elements.  You could use `execute_script()` to set the value of the `select`.  Having said that, I suspect some visible element on the page is setting the `select`.  You should probably figure out what element that is, and interact with that.

Comment: @Richard In case of execute_script the triggers activated from selecting won't be triggered, so I won't be able to see the new elements pop-up, for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `execute_script()` to set the display property of that element and then use the Selenium `Select` for selecting a required value.

Below code should work for you:

```
    try:
      selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'some_other_id_on_page')))
      selenium.execute_script("document.getElementById('some_id').style.display='inline-block';")
      element = selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'some_id')))
      selenium.webdriver.support.ui.Select(element).select_by_value('1')
    except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: WebDriverWait will throw an exception because web element is not really visible

Comment: Okay. See the updated code, for first WebDriverWait you can check the visibility of any other element on the page, so that we are sure web page is loaded properly and after that we can change the display property of select tag,