# Not able to enter text when style=display: inline-block; with Webdriver Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML from the website:

```
<td class="loginPassword">
<input name="_ctl0$MainContentPlaceHolder$oSession$oPwdID" type="password" maxlength="50" id="oPwdID" tabindex="2" class="signin login-input-rounded" autocomplete="off" data-i18n="[title]LoginPage.Password" title="Password" style="display: none;">
<input name="_ctl0$MainContentPlaceHolder$oSession$txtPlainPassword" type="text" id="txtPlainPassword" tabindex="2" class="graytext login-input-rounded" data-i18n="[value]LoginPage.Password" value="Password" style="display: inline-block;">
<input type="hidden" name="_ctl0$MainContentPlaceHolder$oSession$elqCustomerGUID" id="elqCustomerGUID"></td>
```

Here is my code:

```
findPasswordField = driver.find_element_by_id("txtPlainPassword").click()

driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#txtPlainPassword').style.display='block';")

driver.find_element_by_id("txtPlainPassword").send_keys("papsp")
```

It clicks the password element but String "papsp" is not getting entered.

It throws the following Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

I tried using the following stackoverflow answer, Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958193/how-to-select-any-element-from-the-web-element-with-display-none-attribute-us)!

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I thought it should work.

Please let me know if anything is not clear or more information is required.

Comment: In general, you don't want to use JSE to change the state of elements because users won't interact with the page in that way. Find how the element becomes enabled, visible, etc. and code that. If you will share a link to the page, we can take a look.

Comment: Here is the link:
[https://member.virginpulse.com/login.aspx]

Comment: Why don't you use JS to set the values directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to handle wrong element. Try to use below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_id('oUserID').send_keys('userName'+Keys.TAB)
driver.find_element_by_id('oPwdID').send_keys('papsp')
```

Comment: Ah, Exactly!! Should have looked harder, For some reason I kept looking at other line of code. 

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I am not able to enter. I can see the id for login button is oLogon
I can have another question but was wondering if you can help.
I tried your code and I added the following:
    `btn = driver.find_element_by_id('oLogon')
btn.submit()`

Also tried:
`driver.find_element_by_id('oPwdID').send_keys('papsp' + Keys.ENTER)`

Even:
`driver.find_element_by_id('oPwdID').send_keys('papsp'+ Keys.RETURN)`

It doesn't work

Comment: and what about simple `driver.find_element_by_id('oLogon').click()`? Do you get any exception?

Comment: I tried that before, no Error but the screen doesn't do anything.
Link here: (https://snag.gy/FUn28I.jpg)

But if I enter wrong username which is not registered:
Then it gives me an error, Link here : (https://snag.gy/wLf70H.jpg)

I am not sure if it has to do with the security.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue as I have no account there.. You might need to `import time` and to add `time.sleep(1)` between actions to make your script behave more like human

Comment: That does it, Thanks